# Android, Gradle. How start specific instrumented test method?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

When I want to start specific local unit test (in folder "test") I start (**Dev** is buildType):

```
  gradlew testDevUnitTest --tests com.example.StringUtilTest.testMethod
```

OK. It's work.

But also I want to start specific instrumented test method (in folder "androidTest").

```
gradlew connectedDevAndroidTest --tests com.example.StringUtilTest.testSelectLanguageFragment
```

But I get error:

```
> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run all tests in a specific test class like this

```
gradlew connectedDevAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.StringUtilTest
```

You can run a single test in a specific test class like this

```
gradlew connectedDevAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.StringUtilTest#testSelectLanguageFragment
```

More info at https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html

Comment: I want to start specific instrumented test method (not class). Suppose in test class I have 3 test methods. I want to start only method#2. How I can do this?

Comment: Here the solution. This work: 

gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.mynamespace.MyActivityTest#myTestMethod

Comment: yep that's what i put in the answer above i believe

Comment: To run tests for more than one class, separate them with a comma: `gradlew connectedDevAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.StringUtilTest,com.example.OtherTest`