# How to exlude tests when generating coverage reports using Jacoco on Android with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I want to run a single Gradle command which generates a coverage report as well as runs a specific set of tests, not every test in the package. In this instance, I want to generate the report on my instrumentation tests and not on my UI tests.

I have set up Jacoco so that I can run the Gradle command 
`./gradlew create<package-name>DebugAndroidTestCoverageReport` to run all of my tests in the androidTest folder.

I've tried `./gradlew create<package-name>DebugAndroidTestCoverageReport --tests "com.myproject.test.*"` to only run the tests located in the `test` package but this returns the error `Unknown command-line option '--tests'`.

Using the Gradle command `test --tests "com.myproject.test.*"` Works fine and runs the specified tests, but does not generate the coverage report.

Is there a way that I can have test filtering while still generating the coverage report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I stumbled upon this question [Android, Gradle. How start specific instrumented test method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513484/android-gradle-how-start-specific-instrumented-test-method) which gave me the answer.

In order to filter out test cases by package you can use

`./gradlew create<package-name>DebugAndroidTestCoverageReport -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.package=com.example.test`

This command will generate the coverage report only on the specified tests.